# What would a Special training school for Agents look like?

Tags: survival

What would a Special training school for Agents look like?
It's a School where Agents have to be trained to survive in every weather condition, where they also learn how to survive in the Wilderness on their own, learn how to help themselves if they are injured, they would also have to be able to handle every weapon, and know a lot of stuff about aliens.

EDIT:

The agents are actually part of a special force for fighting against aliens, they should be able to survive on their own in the worst circumstances. So that if the aliens attack humanity and the apocalypse breaks out they should be able to survive no matter what.

If they have to go to another planet they should be able to survive there too, they should know about aliens, biology, physics, weapons etc. and the goal of the agency is trying to protect earth and humanity from aliens

Comment: You need to expand your definition. Who do these "agents" work for, what is their agency trying to achieve and so on. The other thing you need to be aware of is technically an "Agent" is a citizen of one country recruited by a second country to gather intelligence. A Russian recruited by the CIA to spy on Russia is an Agent, an American going into Russia for a mission is an "Operator". James Bond is an Operator who often recruits women to become Agents...(among other duties).

Comment: Apart from the aliens part, you just described modern day training for special forces like SEALs.

Comment: @Thucydides It could also be Special Agent, as in someone who works for the FBI. It doesn't have to be a spy of any kind, as the question doesn't specify that, among many other things.

Comment: @Thucydides hmm i see, well then let me explain it in more detail, so these agents, i called them agents but actually are a special force for fighting against aliens, they should be able to survive on their own in the worst circumstances so that if the aliens attack humanity and the apocalypse brakes out they should be able to survive no mater what, or if they have to go to another planet they should be able to survive that 2, they should know about aliens, biology, physics, weapons ect. and the goal of the agency is trying to protect earth and humanity from aliens

Comment: I might suggest you edit the question to add these factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I propose the school be set up in a plane capable of landing on a primitive airstrip.**

- survive in every weather condition
- survive in the wilderness

To get to various weather and wildernesses the school would need to be mobile.

- handle every weapon

You would need an environment where you could practice with every weapon.  This would entail a shooting range, at least and possibly a large outdoor range for heavy weaponry.  This would have to be outside the plane but the plane could go there or be based nearby.

- first aid / know about aliens

This sounds like classroom stuff, and could take place on the plane en route to the wildnerness and harsh weather.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with a mobile operation base I would use a ship between the size of modern destroyers and aircraft carriers, for the following reasons:

- information, material and personel can be tightly controlled to avoid that the public or the aliens get to gather intelligence
- can offer a safe place in case of an invasion
- is fast enough to reach different continents
- has enough storage room for smaller vehicles and maybe even an escape rocket that could allow a dozen agents to reach a spaceship waiting in earths orbit
- is large enough for a shooting range, different simulation rooms and other facilities to provide the training required